# Google Apps Script - How to stop new messages from going into old threads?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I have a Google Apps script that parses through threads with a label "incoming", fires them off to a webhook, and then marks them as "sent".

```
function send() {
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('incoming');
    var sentlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('sent');
    var messages = [];
    var threads = label.getThreads();

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        messages = messages.concat(threads[i].getMessages())
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var message = messages[i];
        Logger.log(message);

        var payload = {
            "from": message.getFrom(),
            "to": message.getTo(),
            "cc": message.getCc(),
            "date": message.getDate(),
            "subject": message.getSubject(),
            "txtbody": message.getPlainBody()
        };

        var options = {
            'method': 'post',
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
        };

        var webhookUrl = '<redacted>';
        UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhookUrl, options);
    }

    // remove the label from these threads so we don't send them to
    // slack again next time the script is run
    label.removeFromThreads(threads);
    Utilities.sleep(200);
    sentlabel.addToThreads(threads);

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i].moveToArchive();
    }
}
```

The problem is, because these emails are generated by a service, they have similar subjects - sometimes the same subject (I can't change this in the service)

Let's say the subject is "Update on X1".

When an email comes in for "Update on X1" - the script works fine, sends it off no worries.

But, if a new "Update on X1" comes in, it sends both the new one and the old one since Gmail labels the whole thread.

This results in heavy duplication. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to shed some light into Thread labels on Gmail.

As of now (and for the perceivable future), a thread will have all the labels from it's messages.

This is still helpful to you, as you can quickly isolate which Threads contain messages with the *"incoming"* label.

If instead of 'incoming' you meant messages on the Inbox (received messages), then you can look for the label 'INBOX', as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#types_of_labels).

By having this sub-list of messages, you can then process the contained messages with [`thread.getMessages()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getMessages()). Then you can use the [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) for Gmail in order to call the [`Users.messages.get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) to retrieve the [`Message`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages) representation, including it's list of labels `labelIds[]`.

You can then manipulate each message and add the labels to them when your messages are sent.

---

## Alternative solution

Another solution would be to have some form of storage where you store the already processed `messageId`s, then check for those before sending them to you webhook.

You can do this with a [JDBC connection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) on Apps Script, [Firebase Realtime Database](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) or even your own DIY Google Docs solution.

This is not a requirement, but can be useful if you wish to store the messages for long-term querying outside of Gmail.

Comment: "as you can quickly isolate which Threads contain messages with the "incoming" label."

.... how? You just casually mention this with no explanation.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without external services or bringing up servers on google cloud? I just want a simple email forward to a webhook. Gmail is making this much harder that it had to be. All It should have been was "If message = new, send, now message = sent"

Comment: @NictraSavios to get messages with a specific label you can look at the code on your quesiton. `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('incomming');`. If instead of 'incoming' you meant messages on the Inbox (received messages), then you can look for the label 'INBOX', as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#types_of_labels).

As of your second question, Apps Script does not require a server on Google Cloud or an external service. My alternative solution would use it for long-term storage of which messages were sent or not, but that's not required for the action to happen.